# LEFT JOIN tables mysql, not getting the data correctly

Tags: mysql, join

I don't know if this is a problem with my query, or if I am using the wrong thing altogether.

Basically I have 2 tables, submission_data and codes. The codes can be managed in the system, and numbers are submitted against each code in the submissions page. However, if a new code is added after some submissions have been added, the query I use to grab all of the data for a specific submission does not show any new codes added as it is not present in the submission_data table.

[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/985da3/1)

My query is as follows:

```
SELECT c.code, sd.code_value from submission_data sd 
LEFT JOIN codes c ON c.ID = sd.code_id 
WHERE submission_id = 1
```

I should be seeing the S code in the results, obvsiously with a value of 0 as there are no entries.

Have I done the query the wrong way around (selecting from the wrong table first), or is it something to do with my JOINS? I have tried different combinations and keep getting the same results

Comment: `LEFT JOIN` ensures the result set will contain all the rows from the left table (`submission_data` in this case), even when they do not match rows from the right table using the join condition. If you need all the rows from `codes` either put it on the left (`FROM codes c LEFT JOIN submission_data...`) or use `RIGHT JOIN` (which is the same as left join but with left and right swapped).

Comment: I have tried that but I still get the same results

Comment: Oh, you're right. The `WHERE` condition filters out the rows from `codes` that do not have a match in `submission_data` because they will be paired with a row full of `NULL`s and you check for `sd.submission_id = 1. Move the `sd.submission_id = 1` condition to the join and put `codes` on the left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query should work:

```
SELECT c.code, sd.code_value 
FROM codes c
LEFT JOIN submission_data sd  ON c.ID = sd.code_id AND submission_id = 1
```

It gets all the rows from `codes`. For each row from `codes` it finds all the matches (by `code.ID`) from `submission_data` that also have `submission_id = 1`. If no such row is found in `submission_data`, it returns `NULL` for `sd.code_value`.

Comment: Brilliant, that worked! Such a simple fix too, i have been looking at this way too long for anything to make sense. Cheers man! +1